# concatenate two List calculated columns into one

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I am new in SharePoint so please forgive me if I am not using the right terminology.
I have a list with several columns (some are calculated columns) and I was doing fine until I hit my column limitation for calculation.
In Column A "Budget Risk", I have sum of several numbers
In column B "Budget Risk Rating", I have a condition
In column C "Risk / Rating", I "concatenate" column A and B

[image]

Is there a way to combine column A and B into one column?

I tried this in Excel since Excel uses the same formula but get "0" for answer or error message.

If I don't make any sense please let me know and I will give you more detail information.
Thanks in advance.

R

Comment: I came across this question while searching for something else. I think the question is very unclear. Can you please illustrate both the desired result and the actual result you are getting?

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use ";" instead of ",". Like this:

```
Budget Risk/Rating -> =CONCATENATE([Budget Risk];"/";[Budget Risk Rating])
```

Comment: I don't think semicolons are proper syntax.

Comment: using semicolons or commas depends on your international settings. If you are using US settings you should use commas, for most European countries you should use semicolons

Answer (score 2):

My guess is you have too many () around your concatenate statement? Alternatively, try using & instead...

```
Use the ampersand (&) operator or the CONCATENATE function to do this task.

COLUMN1 COLUMN2 FORMULA                             DESCRIPTION
Nancy   Fuller  =Column1&Column2                    Combines the two strings (NancyFuller)
Nancy   Fuller  =Column1&" "&Column2                Combines the two strings, separated by a space (Nancy Fuller)
Nancy   Fuller  =Column2&","&Column1                Combines the two strings, separated by a comma (Fuller,Nancy)
Nancy   Fuller  =CONCATENATE(Column2, ",", Column1) Combines the two strings, separated by a comma (Fuller,Nancy)
```

source: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/examples-of-common-formulas-HA001160947.aspx